NextJS "Error: Invariant failed" with no error message during build
I'm trying to build a NextJS app locally. The app builds successfully on Vercel but does not build locally. I've tried to replicate the same conditions as on Vercel (e.g. make the same env vars available), but somehow can't get the app to build.
Here's the output:
root@9249b25664a4:/app/apps/web# dotenv -o ../../.env.local -- pnpm next build --debug --no-mangling --no-lint
 ⚠ Linting is disabled.
 ⚠ Mangling is disabled. Note: This may affect performance and should only be used for debugging purposes.
  ▲ Next.js 14.2.4

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Checking validity of types
   Collecting page data  ..Error: Invariant failed
    at i (/app/apps/web/.next/server/chunks/1164.js:4:122867)
    at 70364 (/app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/best/route.js:1:3568)
    at t (/app/apps/web/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 68930 (/app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/best/route.js:1:1355)
    at t (/app/apps/web/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at r (/app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/best/route.js:1:6004)
    at /app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/best/route.js:1:6047
    at t.X (/app/apps/web/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1206)
    at /app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/best/route.js:1:6017
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/best/route.js:1:6075)
Error: Invariant failed
    at i (/app/apps/web/.next/server/chunks/1164.js:4:122867)
    at 70364 (/app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/reliability/route.js:1:2639)
    at t (/app/apps/web/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 61279 (/app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/reliability/route.js:1:1344)
    at t (/app/apps/web/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at r (/app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/reliability/route.js:1:5075)
    at /app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/reliability/route.js:1:5113
    at t.X (/app/apps/web/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1206)
    at /app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/reliability/route.js:1:5088
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/metrics/reliability/route.js:1:5141)

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/metrics/best
    at /app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1268:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}

Does anyone know why this happens? How can I get the actual error message out from Invariant failed (it seems like other occurrences of this error mentioned online are accompanied by additional details). Also, if it reruns the build command, it seems like the page fails to collect changes.
All of the following results in the same error:
turbo run build --env-mode=loose
dotenv -o ../../.env.local -- pnpm next build --debug --no-mangling --no-lint
dotenv -o ../../.env.local -- pnpm next build
pnpm next build
I expect the app to build like in Vercel.
